# Saving a png imaging with PIL

Tags: image, save, python-imaging-library

I am rather new to python and have a problem with the save function of the  of PIL when I want run the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ImageFont
import Image
import ImageDraw
from PIL import Image
img=Image.new("RGB", (200,200),(120,20,20))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0),"This is a test",(255,255,0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("test.png")
```

I have this error I don't know why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ima2.py", line 9, in <module>
    draw.text((0, 0),"This is a test",(255,255,0))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 260, in text
    font = self.getfont()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py", line 133, in getfont
    self.font = ImageFont.load_default()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 377, in load_default
    '''))))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 117, in _load_pilfont_data
    image.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 192, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 381, in _getdecoder
    raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder zip not available
```

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your fonts, and probably PIL install, rather than saving.  Try a search using the last line of your traceback: ie, "PIL IOError: decoder zip not available" and you'll find a bunch of suggestions that might apply to your situation.  (Nicely phrased question with a good self-contained, minimal example, btw... a good way to get good answers!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are not applying any font to your text.
Try this:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("C:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf", 24)             
draw.text((0, 0),"Sample Text",(255,255,255),font=font)
```